# Count the number of non-isomorphic 6-regular graphs on 9 vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I know there will be 9 vertices of degree 6, which means there are 54 edges. But then how will I figure out the number of non-isomorphic graphs?

Comment: @The number of edges is 27.

Comment: Ha, forgot the overcount :P.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** It is a lot easier to count their complements.

Comment: I assume the complement is a 2-regular graph on 9 vertices correct?

Comment: @HenryLee: Correct,

Comment: That would mean there's only one graph though...is it only one?

Comment: @HenryLee: No, there are four. (Are you perhaps imagining that the complement has to be connected?)

Comment: Wouldn't it have to because it's 2-regular?

Comment: @HenryLee: Why would it? For example, a 5-cycle next to a 4-cycle is a perfectly good 2-regular graph on 9 vertices.

Answer (score 0):

They can be generated using `geng` which is packaged with Nauty using the command `./geng 9 -d6 -D6`.  Feeding this into `showg` will show the adjacencies of the graphs, which we draw as follows:

[image: the non-isomorphic 6-regular graphs on 9 vertices]

We color the non-edges red and identify the complement graphs below each graph.  We can readily see why it's easier to count the 2-regular graphs and take their complements.

Since isomorphims map edges to edges, and non-edges to non-edges, two graphs are isomorphic if and only if their complements are isomorphic.